# databricks-connect, Py4JJavaError while trying to use collect()

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-connect

I'm encountering an issue while running the following line of code in JupyterLab, which is connected to a Spark cluster:

```
df.select('col_1').distinct().collect()
```

This exact code executes successfully in a Databricks notebook, but when run locally, it results in an error. My environment includes Java 8 and databricks-connect version 10.4.40.

the issue arises only with operations that attempt to return data to Python, example: toPandas/related.

```
/tmp/ipykernel_53/2883452107.py:1 in <module>                                                    │
│                                                                                                  │
│ [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/ipykernel_53/2883452107.py'                           │
│                                                                                                  │
│ /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py:715 in collect                   │
│                                                                                                  │
│    712 │   │   │   │   os.remove(filename)                                                       │
│    713 │   │   # Default path used in OSS Spark / for non-DF-ACL clusters:                       │
│    714 │   │   with SCCallSiteSync(self._sc) as css:                                             │
│ ❱  715 │   │   │   sock_info = self._jdf.collectToPython()                                       │
│    716 │   │   return list(_load_from_socket(sock_info, BatchedSerializer(PickleSerializer())))  │
│    717 │                                                                                         │
│    718 │   def toLocalIterator(self, prefetchPartitions=False):                                  │
│                                                                                                  │
│ ╭───────────────── locals ──────────────────╮                                                    │
│ │  css = None                               │                                                    │
│ │ self = DataFrame[CD_COMP: decimal(38,18)] │                                                    │
│ ╰───────────────────────────────────────────╯                                                    │
│                                                                                                  │
│ /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py:1304 in __call__                     │
│                                                                                                  │
│   1301 │   │   │   proto.END_COMMAND_PART                                                        │
│   1302 │   │                                                                                     │
│   1303 │   │   answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)                                │
│ ❱ 1304 │   │   return_value = get_return_value(                                                  │
│   1305 │   │   │   answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)                       │
│   1306 │   │                                                                                     │
│   1307 │   │   for temp_arg in temp_args:                                                        │
│                                                                                                  │
│ ╭──────────────────────────────── locals ────────────────────────────────╮                       │
│ │       answer = 'xro101'                                                │                       │
│ │         args = ()                                                      │                       │
│ │ args_command = ''                                                      │                       │
│ │      command = 'c\no98\ncollectToPython\ne\n'                          │                       │
│ │         self = <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7f3b137ecaf0> │                       │
│ │    temp_args = []                                                      │                       │
│ ╰────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╯                       │
│                                                                                                  │
│ /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyspark/sql/utils.py:117 in deco                          │
│                                                                                                  │
│   114 def capture_sql_exception(f):                                                              │
│   115 │   def deco(*a, **kw):                                                                    │
│   116 │   │   try:                                                                               │
│ ❱ 117 │   │   │   return f(*a, **kw)                                                             │
│   118 │   │   except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:                                           │
│   119 │   │   │   converted = convert_exception(e.java_exception)                                │
│   120 │   │   │   if not isinstance(converted, UnknownException):                                │
│                                                                                                  │
│ ╭─────────────────────────────────────────── locals ───────────────────────────────────────────╮ │
│ │         a = (                                                                                │ │
│ │             │   'xro101',                                                                    │ │
│ │             │   <py4j.clientserver.JavaClient object at 0x7f3afed79280>,                     │ │
│ │             │   'o98',                                                                       │ │
│ │             │   'collectToPython'                                                            │ │
│ │             )                                                                                │ │
│ │ converted = UnknownException('java.lang.NumberFormatException: null',                        │ │
│ │             'java.lang.NumberFormatException: null\n\tat                                     │ │
│ │             java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:552)\n\tat                                    │ │
│ │             java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:631)\n\tat                                    │ │
│ │             scala.collection.immutable.StringLike.toLong(StringLike.scala:309)\n\tat         │ │
│ │             scala.collection.immutable.StringLike.toLong$(StringLike.scala:309)\n\tat        │ │
│ │             scala.collection.immutable.StringOps.toLong(StringOps.scala:33)\n\tat            │ │
│ │             com.databricks.spark.util.DatabricksConnectConf$.$anonfun$getOrgId$2(Databricks… │ │
│ │             com.databricks.spark.util.DatabricksConnectConf$.$anonfun$getOrgId$2$adapted(Da… │ │
│ │             scala.Option.map(Option.scala:230)\n\tat                                         │ │
│ │             com.databricks.spark.util.DatabricksConnectConf$.getOrgId(DatabricksConnectConf… │ │
│ │             com.databricks.sql.DatabricksSQLConf$.$anonfun$SPARK_SERVICE_ORG_ID$1(Databrick… │ │
│ │             scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcJ$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcJ$sp.java:23)\n\tat     │ │
│ │             org.apache.spark.internal.config.ConfigEntryWithDefaultFunction.defaultValueStr… │ │
│ │             org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SQLConf.$anonfun$getAllDefaultConfs$1(SQLConf.sca… │ │
│ │             scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:943)\n\tat                      │ │
│ │             scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:943)\n\tat                     │ │
│ │             scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1431)\n\tat             │ │
│ │             scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach(IterableLike.scala:74)\n\tat               │ │
│ │             scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach$(IterableLike.scala:73)\n\tat              │ │
│ │             scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:56)\n\tat               │ │
│ │             org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SQLConf.getAllDefaultConfs(SQLConf.scala:4954)\n\… │ │
│ │             org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SQLConf.recordNonDefaultConfs(SQLConf.scala:4968)… │ │
│ │             org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withCustomExecutionEnv$8(… │ │
│ │             org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution… │ │
│ │             org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withCustomExecutionEnv$1(… │ │
│ │             org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:968)\n\tat       │ │
│ │             org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withCustomExecutionEnv(SQLExecutio… │ │
│ │             org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.sc… │ │
│ │             org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3949)\n\tat                │ │
│ │             org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.collectToPython(Dataset.scala:3737)\n\tat           │ │
│ │             sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\n\tat                │ │
│ │             sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)\n… │ │
│ │             sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.ja… │ │
│ │             java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)\n\tat                           │ │
│ │             py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)\n\tat               │ │
│ │             py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:380)\n\tat         │ │
│ │             py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:295)\n\tat                                      │ │
│ │             py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)\n\tat       │ │
│ │             py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)\n\tat                     │ │
│ │             py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:195)\n\… │ │
│ │             py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:115)\n\tat           │ │
│ │             java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)\n', None)                                  │ │
│ │         f = <function get_return_value at 0x7f3b1b3b2550>                                    │ │
│ │        kw = {}                                                                               │ │
│ ╰──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╯ │
│                                                                                                  │
│ /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/py4j/protocol.py:326 in get_return_value                  │
│                                                                                                  │
│   323 │   │   │   type = answer[1]                                                               │
│   324 │   │   │   value = OUTPUT_CONVERTER[type](answer[2:], gateway_client)                     │
│   325 │   │   │   if answer[1] == REFERENCE_TYPE:                                                │
│ ❱ 326 │   │   │   │   raise Py4JJavaError(                                                       │
│   327 │   │   │   │   │   "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".                        │
│   328 │   │   │   │   │   format(target_id, ".", name), value)                                   │
│   329 │   │   │   else:                                                                          │
│                                                                                                  │
│ ╭───────────────────────────────── locals ─────────────────────────────────╮                     │
│ │         answer = 'xro101'                                                │                     │
│ │ gateway_client = <py4j.clientserver.JavaClient object at 0x7f3afed79280> │                     │
│ │           name = 'collectToPython'                                       │                     │
│ │      target_id = 'o98'                                                   │                     │
│ │           type = 'r'                                                     │                     │
│ │          value = JavaObject id=o101                                      │                     │
│ ╰──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╯                     │
╰──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╯
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o98.collectToPython.
: java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
        at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:552)
        at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:631)
        at scala.collection.immutable.StringLike.toLong(StringLike.scala:309)
        at scala.collection.immutable.StringLike.toLong$(StringLike.scala:309)
        at scala.collection.immutable.StringOps.toLong(StringOps.scala:33)
        at com.databricks.spark.util.DatabricksConnectConf$.$anonfun$getOrgId$2(DatabricksConnectConf.scala:94)
        at 
com.databricks.spark.util.DatabricksConnectConf$.$anonfun$getOrgId$2$adapted(DatabricksConnectConf.scala:94)
        at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:230)
        at com.databricks.spark.util.DatabricksConnectConf$.getOrgId(DatabricksConnectConf.scala:94)
        at com.databricks.sql.DatabricksSQLConf$.$anonfun$SPARK_SERVICE_ORG_ID$1(DatabricksSQLConf.scala:1879)
        at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcJ$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcJ$sp.java:23)
        at 
org.apache.spark.internal.config.ConfigEntryWithDefaultFunction.defaultValueString(ConfigEntry.scala:170)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SQLConf.$anonfun$getAllDefaultConfs$1(SQLConf.scala:4956)
        at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:943)
        at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:943)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1431)
        at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach(IterableLike.scala:74)
        at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach$(IterableLike.scala:73)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:56)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SQLConf.getAllDefaultConfs(SQLConf.scala:4954)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SQLConf.recordNonDefaultConfs(SQLConf.scala:4968)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withCustomExecutionEnv$8(SQLExecution.scala:196)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:393)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withCustomExecutionEnv$1(SQLExecution.scala:192)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:968)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withCustomExecutionEnv(SQLExecution.scala:147)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:343)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3949)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.collectToPython(Dataset.scala:3737)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:380)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:295)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:195)
        at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:115)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
```

I've tried with different java versions/different pandas versions but nothing solved the problem.

Comment: Provide the details how you configured spark locally.

Comment: I'm passing the arguments necessary (url, token, org_id, cluster_id and port) to my spark and executing it. After this I can just use the same context in other parts of my code.

Answer (score 0):

First, ensure that you are using the correct version of `databricks-connect` that matches your Databricks runtime.

If your runtime is `13`, you need to install `databricks-connect` version 13.

For Databricks runtime 12.2 and below, follow this [documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/en/dev-tools/databricks-connect-legacy.html#set-up-legacy); if it is 13.0 and above, use this [documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/en/dev-tools/databricks-connect/python/index.html).

The error you are encountering is due to the presence of `null` or `empty strings` that are being converted to `Long`. If the type doesn't match, null is automatically added.

[image]

In your case, the issue may be a version mismatch between `databricks-connect` and the Databricks runtime.

If you still encounter the same error after checking the versions, remove records with `null` values or strip the string to eliminate spaces in your column.

Comment: The versions are correct. I ran it in a docker and it worked correctly (with volume and using the same libraries/environment as before). In the docker it worked but in some local computers it didn't. In short: the docker solved the problem. Should I post the docker here? Later in the week I'll debug a little bit more the docker to see where it stops working (to replicate the same problem other computers had).

Comment: Yes. it will be help full  to reproduce the issue.

Comment: What is your databricks runtime?

Comment: It's 10.4, therefore I'm using databricks-connect==10.4.*, so the versions are fine